# How to create a 'hubspot webhook like' in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, webhooks, salesforce-lightning, hubspot

In Hubspot we have a the webhook solution to receive in a endpoint the updates from the users that assign a connected app.
Ex.: If a user that changed a 'Contact' in hubspot I will receive this change in my app.

Is there something similar for Salesforce?
How can I get the information from a 'Contact' update from a connected app user in salesforce?